# msoFileDialogFilePicker opens behind active application

Tags: vb6, openfiledialog

Im doing this project and everything is working fine except this little detail. The FileDiaogFilePicker opens on top of the app when run on vb6 editor but when I build it as an exe file the file picker shows behind the application. I've tried searching through internet but I can't seem to find the solution still. I hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: All FileDialog objects are modal so once a dialog box is displayed, no code continues to execute until the dialog box is dismissed. Could you give more details about your code/app/project, so we try to give some help ?

Comment: Can you show some code? And is this actually a VBA macro code, in Excel or Word?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Dim lcount As Long  
getfoldername = vbNullString  

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)  
.InitialFileName = OpenAt
'.Show

If .Show = -1 Then  
For lcount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count  
getfoldername = .SelectedItems(lcount)  
Next lcount  
txtsave.Text = getfoldername & "\"  
Else  
Exit Sub  
End If  
End With
```

I just found that in the web as well so I have no idea if it is a Macro code.